# $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, prove $|gHg^{-1}| = |H|$, $\forall g \in G$

Tags: group-theory

> $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, prove $|gHg^{-1}| = |H|$, $\forall g \in G$

Here's what I know:

If $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ then the statement is trivial.

If $H$ is not a normal subgroup of $G$ then we know $|H| | |G|$ by Lagrange's Theorem (although I'm not sure if this is helpful).

Where else can I go from here?

Is my approach correct?

Comment: You only have to show that if $ghg^{-1}=gh'g^{-1}$ then $h=h'$.

Comment: show that $h\mapsto g^{-1}hg$ is a bijection $H\to gHg^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $$\begin{align}\phi_g: H&\to gHg^{-1}\\ h&\mapsto ghg^{-1}\end{align}$$ is a bijection with inverse $$\begin{align}\phi_g^{-1}: gHg^{-1}&\to H\\ \eta&\mapsto g^{-1}\eta g.\end{align}$$ It is called *conjugation by $g$*.

Answer (score 1):

For fixed $g \in G$ we consider the function

$\theta_g:H \to gHg^{-1}; \; \theta_g(h) = ghg^{-1}; \tag 1$

$\theta_g$ is clearly surjective, since every element of $gHG^{-1}$ is, by definition, of the form $ghg^{-1}$ for some $h \in H$; $\theta_g$ is also injective, since if

$gh_1g^{-1} = gh_2g^{-1}, \tag 2$

then

$$\begin{align}h_1 &= e_Gh_1e_G\\
& = (g^{-1}g)h_1(g^{-1}g) \\
&= g^{-1}(gh_1g^{-1})g\\
&= g^{-1}(gh_2g^{-1})g\\
&= (g^{-1}g)h_2(gg^{-1}) \\
&= e_Gh_2e_G\\
&= h_2, \tag 3
\end{align}$$

where $e_G$ is of course the identity element of $G$.

We have thus established that $\theta_g$ is a surjective and injective map 'twixt $H$ and $gHg^{-1}$; by definition, this means that

$\vert H \vert = \vert gHg^{-1} \vert,  \tag 4$

$OE\Delta$.

Comment: This is far superior to my hint of an answer, @jd94. Please accept this instead :)